# Why does it fetch the entity from the database?

Tags: entity-framework

Profiler shows that the select of the new appointment goes to the database. Why isn't the appointment being pulled from the context, which is still in memory?

```
    var context = DatabaseHelper.CreateDbContext();

    var appointment = new Appointment();

    context.Appointments.Add(appointment);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var appointment0 = context.Appointments.Where(a => a.AppointmentId == appointment.AppointmentId).Single();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Entity Framework first-level caching will only be used when you use the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) method.

```
context.Appointments.Find( a => a.AppointmentId == appointment.AppointmentId)
```

This is understandable, since the query parser does not know which entities will be retrieved by the query.
Only when you explicitely try to find an entity based on its primary key, the DbContext (which implements the [Identity Map](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) pattern) can first look up if there's already an entity associated for the given primary key.

Comment: Although my code is doing a primary key lookup. So it's not altogether understandable.

Comment: Entity Framework does not know upfront that what the resultset of that query will be, so it has to execute it.   Only when EF is sure that you do a lookup using a primary key, it can first check its identity map.